# How much iron ore is there?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I play Minecraft on the Xbox. I'm a bit of a resource hoarder. I'm just wondering if I need to be.

I know that there are a lot of resources in the world, but I also know that the world is of a limited size (currently 864 x 864) - thus there is a limit to the amount of resources that one can collect.

Is there an a way to predict how many of the valuable, non-renewable resources (specifically iron, gold and diamond) there are in the world? Yes, I realize this would vary greatly depending on the numbers of each biome that generates with a world (a dominately ocean world would likely have fewer resources).

*Note:* Currently iron is not renewable

- there are no iron golems
- it is not a drop (even a rare one) by any mob
- trading has not been implemented

Comment: As a person that only owns a PC, does Minecraft for XBox have worlds of limited size?

Comment: @user1337 currently the world is limited to 864 x 864.

Comment: If it's anything like the PC version there is a % chance for it to spawn. Then do the math for how big the world. For example iron ore, 0.72% of stone from rows 2-61; maybe someone will be nice enough to do it for you.

Comment: @tony, where did you find the number 0.72%?

Comment: @ChargingPun http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Minecraft_Wiki

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The average number of iron ores per chunk is [77](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_Ore#Natural_Occurrence). Although this information comes from the full game, the distribution does not appear to have changed since the version that xbox Minecraft is based on.

There are 54 * 54 chunks in xbox Minecraft.

77 * 54 * 54 = **224532** iron ingots on average.

Comment: I think your math might be off, since 54 x 54 x 77 = 224532. But otherwise this is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: That's a lot of iron.

Comment: For completeness, the average Gold: 21870, and Diamands: 8748.

Comment: @ChargingPun I blame google.